# Decoding h.264 Live Stream and Display in Unity

Tags: c#, c++, streaming, unity-game-engine, h.264

Well i am Designing a embedded system which has a webcam and will stream a h.264 video over the network.

I want to read that stream (from LAN) decode the H.264 stream and display it on the Screen. 
It has to be a fullscreen application. Yes it has to be in Unity.

Any pointers to like where to start from?

my understanding
unity has webcamTexture but that can decode only mjpeg stream?

i'l will have to like make a x264decoder.dll and import it to Unity so using the dll it will decode the incoming video and apply it to a texture?

Comment: I'm working on something similar at the moment, the movieTexture object is too slow to render 4k video at 60fps so I wrote a plugin (dll) which reads to a dynamic texture and in the unity callback copies to a target texture. It's pretty trivial and quite similar to the plugin demo unity supplies

Comment: i haven not gone anywhere with it :/
was looking at h.264 decoders available but well i cant get the graphEdit part fused with Unity.
I looked into Media Foundation Framework .net wrapper but cannot access the h.264 decoder from there. is there any documentation or test samples to work around with media foundation/DShow?

Comment: Got it working ;-) 
External .dll's for the win lol

Comment: what did you use @user2967920 ?

Comment: There is a .NET implementation of ffmpeg called FFmpeg.AutoGen-master, modify the .dll in VS as per your needs to output a color array of r,g,b and access the array from Unity and apply it via the color matrix to a texture (Plane). The Decode delay is around 1-1.5secs on a i5 3rd gen with 8gb RAM and no graphics inside Unity doing 30fps. I moved into a native FormApplication using CUDA + SDL for a better solution, managed 0.2ms latency over 1920x1080@30fps.